# BASH: script to mv paired-end files to subdirectories

Tags: bash

QUESTION: I have a folder of paired-end files and I need to organize these files into subdirectories.

Example of my files:

```
SampleName1_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
SampleName1_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
SampleName2_S2_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
SampleName2_S2_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
...
```

I want the script to create subdirectories and move the files like:

```
SampleName1_S1_Analysis/
SampleName1_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz SampleName1_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz

SampleName2_S2_Analysis/
SampleName2_S2_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz SampleName2_S2_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz

...
```

I've searched around for similar threads, but nothing seems to satisfy my question. Any assistance will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: The fact that these are genetic sequencing files has nothing whatsoever to do with the question and should not be part of the title.  Additionally, you need to try to solve the problem yourself and share what you've tried in the question before SO will help.

Comment: Is the directory name determined by splitting at the second underscore? Or by looking for `_L`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need a script for this, simply execute this commands in this order:

Edited (I guess this might help):

```
#!bin/bash
for file in *.fastq.gz; do
 if [ -e "$file" ]; then
  name=$(echo "$file" | cut -d'_' -f1,2)
  mkdir "${name}_Analysis" && mv "${name}"*.fastq.gz "${name}_Analysis"
 fi;
done;
```

Comment: I want to automate the process because I have more than 30 samples and they're increasing.

Comment: I modified my answer

Comment: For file operations, and for bash in general it is best practice to quote variables i.e. "$file" - to avoid troubles with files with spaces in it.

Comment: You'll want to fix the syntax error.  Try http://shellcheck.net/ for detailed diagnostics.

Comment: **@GustavoTopete**, that exactly what I need. Thanks

Comment: @AbdulrahmanMI no problem!, I'm glad I could help, I still being a newbie with bash, so feel free to tell me any errors I might have

Comment: A couple of thoughts for a `bash` newbie... 1) It is advisable to add `shopt -s nullglob` before using a `for` loop, in case there are no matching files. 2) Your test for file existence is unnecessary, it must exist or it wouldn't be in the list. 3) The `mkdir` would probably be better with `mkdir -p` so it wouldn't give an error if you ran it twice and the target directory already existed. 4) The first parameter to `mv` is more simply expressed as `"$file"`

Answer (score 0):

I think `rename` is the tool to use here:

```
rename --dry-run -p 's|_L.*|_Analysis/$_|' *gz
```

**Sample Output**

```
'SampleName1_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz' would be renamed to 'SampleName1_S1_Analysis/SampleName1_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz'
'SampleName1_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz' would be renamed to 'SampleName1_S1_Analysis/SampleName1_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz'
'SampleName2_S2_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz' would be renamed to 'SampleName2_S2_Analysis/SampleName2_S2_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz'
'SampleName2_S2_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz' would be renamed to 'SampleName2_S2_Analysis/SampleName2_S2_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz'
```

If the output looks good, run it again without the `--dry-run`.

The `-p` makes output directories as necessary, on the fly.

The name of the current file is passed to the little Perl script in the middle as `$_`. The script then modifies `$_` and `rename` uses that as the new name for the file. I simply strip everything after the `_L` and then append `_Analysis/` to the root of the directory name.

Comment: **@mark,** thanks for your help, your code return usage error: Unknown option: p
Usage:
    rename [ -h|-m|-V ] [ -v ] [ -n ] [ -f ] [ -e|-E *perlexpr*]*|*perlexpr*
    [ *files* ]

Comment: If you are on Centos or some other distros, it may go under the name `prename` a.k.a `Perl rename`.